# How to force a rotating name with python's TimedRotatingFileHandler?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, filehandler

I am trying to use [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler) to keep daily logs in separate log files.
The rotation works perfectly as intended, but what I don't like how it does is the naming of the files.

If I set a log file as my_log_file.log, this will be the "today's" log file, and when it changes day at midnight it will be renamed to `my_log_file.log.2014-07-08` with no .log extension at the end, and a new `my_log_file.log` will be created for the new day.

What I would like to get is the old file being renamed to `my_log_file.2014-07-08.log` or even `my_log_file-2014-07-08.log`, mainly with the .log at the end, not in the middle.
Also, I would like to have the "today's" log file being already named with the today's date, just as the old ones.

Is there any way to do so?

I found that I can personalize the suffix with:

> handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"

But I do not get the way to remove the inner .log part and to force the current log file to have the suffix added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a class ParallelTimedRotatingFileHandler mainly aimed at allowing multiple processes writing in parallel to a log file.
The problems with parallel processes solved by this class, are:

- The rollover moment when all processes are trying to copy or rename the same file at the same time, gives errors.
- The solution for this problem was exactly the naming convention you suggest. So, for a file name `Service` that you supply in the handler, logging does not go to e.g. `Service.log` but today to `Service.2014-08-18.log` and tomorrow `Service.2014-08-19.log`.
- Another solution is to open the files in `a` (append) mode instead of `w` to allow parallel writes.
- Deleting the backup files also needs to be done with caution as multiple parallel processes are deleting the same files at the same time.
- This implementation does not take into account leap seconds (which is not a problem for Unix). In other OS, it might still be 30/6/2008 23:59:60 at the rollover moment, so the date has not changed, so, we take the same file name as yesterday.
- I know that the standard Python recommendation is that the `logging` module is not foreseen for parallel processes, and I should use SocketHandler, but at least in my environment, this works.

The code is just a slight variation of the code in the standard Python handlers.py module. Of course copyright to the copyright holders.

Here is the code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import time
import re

class ParallelTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, postfix = ".log"):

        self.origFileName = filename
        self.when = when.upper()
        self.interval = interval
        self.backupCount = backupCount
        self.utc = utc
        self.postfix = postfix

        if self.when == 'S':
            self.interval = 1 # one second
            self.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
            self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
        elif self.when == 'M':
            self.interval = 60 # one minute
            self.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"
            self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}$"
        elif self.when == 'H':
            self.interval = 60 * 60 # one hour
            self.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%H"
            self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}$"
        elif self.when == 'D' or self.when == 'MIDNIGHT':
            self.interval = 60 * 60 * 24 # one day
            self.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
            self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
        elif self.when.startswith('W'):
            self.interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 # one week
            if len(self.when) != 2:
                raise ValueError("You must specify a day for weekly rollover from 0 to 6 (0 is Monday): %s" % self.when)
            if self.when[1] < '0' or self.when[1] > '6':
                 raise ValueError("Invalid day specified for weekly rollover: %s" % self.when)
            self.dayOfWeek = int(self.when[1])
            self.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
            self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid rollover interval specified: %s" % self.when)

        currenttime = int(time.time())
        logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, self.calculateFileName(currenttime), 'a', encoding, delay)

        self.extMatch = re.compile(self.extMatch)
        self.interval = self.interval * interval # multiply by units requested

        self.rolloverAt = self.computeRollover(currenttime)

    def calculateFileName(self, currenttime):
        if self.utc:
             timeTuple = time.gmtime(currenttime)
        else:
             timeTuple = time.localtime(currenttime)

        return self.origFileName + "." + time.strftime(self.suffix, timeTuple) + self.postfix

    def getFilesToDelete(self, newFileName):
        dirName, fName = os.path.split(self.origFileName)
        dName, newFileName = os.path.split(newFileName)

        fileNames = os.listdir(dirName)
        result = []
        prefix = fName + "."
        postfix = self.postfix
        prelen = len(prefix)
        postlen = len(postfix)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if fileName[:prelen] == prefix and fileName[-postlen:] == postfix and len(fileName)-postlen > prelen and fileName != newFileName:
                 suffix = fileName[prelen:len(fileName)-postlen]
                 if self.extMatch.match(suffix):
                     result.append(os.path.join(dirName, fileName))
        result.sort()
        if len(result) < self.backupCount:
            result = []
        else:
            result = result[:len(result) - self.backupCount]
        return result

     def doRollover(self):
         if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None

         currentTime = self.rolloverAt
         newFileName = self.calculateFileName(currentTime)
         newBaseFileName = os.path.abspath(newFileName)
         self.baseFilename = newBaseFileName
         self.mode = 'a'
         self.stream = self._open()

         if self.backupCount > 0:
             for s in self.getFilesToDelete(newFileName):
                 try:
                     os.remove(s)
                 except:
                     pass

         newRolloverAt = self.computeRollover(currentTime)
         while newRolloverAt <= currentTime:
             newRolloverAt = newRolloverAt + self.interval

         #If DST changes and midnight or weekly rollover, adjust for this.
         if (self.when == 'MIDNIGHT' or self.when.startswith('W')) and not self.utc:
             dstNow = time.localtime(currentTime)[-1]
             dstAtRollover = time.localtime(newRolloverAt)[-1]
             if dstNow != dstAtRollover:
                 if not dstNow:  # DST kicks in before next rollover, so we need to deduct an hour
                     newRolloverAt = newRolloverAt - 3600
                 else:           # DST bows out before next rollover, so we need to add an hour
                     newRolloverAt = newRolloverAt + 3600
         self.rolloverAt = newRolloverAt
```

Comment: I have used this solution as a good one, and It seemed to work exactly as I wanted, until it came the time I use it as it should finally work. When I start the python myself and let it run over midnight, the file swaped correctly, and a new one appeared. But what I really need is a python started by a crontab, and several other pythons started by this first python, and when I do not start the python myself, only the first file is created, at midnight it just stops writing log.
Any idea about why does this happen? Maybe something about linux file privileges?

Comment: Your class didn't work for me without adding first a call to the base constructor on the first line of `__init`: `super().__init__(filename=filename, when=when, interval=interval, backupCount=backupCount, encoding=encoding, delay=delay, utc=utc)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple solution: add a custom namer function to the handler. The logging utility will call your namer function to create the name for the rolled-over file as Jester originally noted like 6 years (!) ago with filename.log.YYYYMMDD, so we need to "move" the  .log part to the end:

```
def namer(name):
    return name.replace(".log", "") + ".log"
```

Then after you've set up your handler just assign your function to its namer attribute:

```
handler.namer = namer
```

Here's my full logging init script, I'm new to python, criticism/advice is welcome:

```
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from config import constants

def namer(name):
    return name.replace(".log", "") + ".log"

def init(baseFilename):
    logPath = constants.LOGGING_DIR
    envSuffix = '-prod' if constants.ENV == 'prod' else '-dev'
    logFilename = os.path.join(logPath, baseFilename + envSuffix + '.log')
    print(f"Logging to {logFilename}")

    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logFilename,
    when = "midnight", 
    backupCount = 30,
    encoding = 'utf8')
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler.suffix = "%Y%m%d"
    handler.namer = namer # <-- Here's where I assign the custom namer.

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s [%(module)s:%(lineno)d]')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logging.basicConfig(
        handlers = [handler],
        format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s [%(module)s:%(lineno)d]',
        level = logging.DEBUG,
        datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init('testing')
    logging.error("ohai")
    logging.debug("ohai debug")
    logging.getLogger().handlers[0].doRollover()
    logging.error("ohai next day")
    logging.debug("ohai debug next day")
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to directly achieve this.

One solution you could try is to override the default behavior.

- Create your own `TimedRotatingFileHandler class` and override the `doRollover() function.`
- Check the source in your python installation `<PythonInstallDir>/Lib/logging/handlers.py`

Something like this:

```
class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def doRollover(self):
        # Do your stuff, rename the file as you want
```

Comment: I already thought about this option, but I hoped there should be an easiest way to do it. If I have no better reply in a couple of weeks I will set this one as the accepted answer, however I will not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I used solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387192/6619512 with Python 3.7 and it is a great solution.

But for 'midnight' *when* parameter and for *when* parameter starting with 'W' it did not work since the *atTime* parameter was introduced and used in the TimedRotatingFileHandler class.

To make use of this solution use the following __init__ line:

```
def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0,
             encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None, postfix = ".log"):
```

Also add the following to the content of the __init__ declarations:

```
self.postfix = postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar question. I ended up making my own class. I tried to keep this a minimal by utilizing the parent class's methods as much as possible. I didn't implement naming including the current log file with the date though.

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


class ExtensionManagingTRFHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, extension='.log', **kwargs):
        if extension:
            if not extension.startswith('.'):
                # ensure extension starts with '.'
                extension = '.' + extension
            if not filename.endswith(extension):
                # make sure not to double the extension
                filename += extension
        super(ExtensionManagingTRFHandler, self).__init__(filename, **kwargs)
        self.extension = extension

    def rotation_filename(self, default_name):
        # remove the extension from the middle and append to end as the default behaviour adds a
        # date suffix after the extension
        result = default_name.replace(self.extension, '')
        result += self.extension
        # the default method applies the self.namer if namer is callable
        result = super(ExtensionManagingTRFHandler, self).rotation_filename(result)
        return result

    def getFilesToDelete(self):
        # this implementation is a bit of a hack in that it temporarily 
        # renames baseFilename and restores it
        slice_size = 0
        if self.baseFilename.endswith(self.extension):
            slice_size = len(self.extension)
            self.baseFilename = self.baseFilename[:-slice_size]
        # the default method still does the heavy lifting
        # this works because it already accounts for the possibility 
        # of a file extension after the dates
        result = super(ExtensionManagingTRFHandler, self).getFilesToDelete()
        if slice_size:
            self.baseFilename += self.extension
        return result
```