# Python Logging - Configuring Rotating File Handler From Config file

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I have the below config file which I am using to configure logging in my python modules , the issue with this is that it does not append the timestamp to the file-name , right now the log file created is file_handler.log but I want it to be file_handler-timestamp.log

```
{
"version": 1,
"disable_existing_loggers": true,
"formatters": {
  "simple": {
    "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s %(lineno)s %(message)s",
    "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  }
},
"handlers": {
  "file_handler": {
    "level": "INFO",
    "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
    "formatter": "simple",
    "filename": "error.log",
    "backupCount": 10,
    "interval" : 1,
    "when": "s",
    "encoding": "utf8"
  }
},
"loggers": { },
"root": {
  "handlers": [
    "file_handler"
  ],
  "level": "DEBUG"
}
}
```

Working code without config

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    
logger = logging.getLogger('log_1')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
handler = RotatingFileHandler('log' + time.strftime('_%Y%m%d-%H%M') + '.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Workaround code which updated the config dynamically when program is initiated

```
import logging.config
import json
import time

fp = open("sample_config.json")
config = json.load(fp)
fp.close()
config['handlers']['file_handler']['filename'] += time.strftime('_%Y%m%d-%H%M') + '.log'
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timestamp` of when? When the file is rotated or when it is created?

If you use `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, then when the file is rotated, the timestamp is appended to the filename.

If you want the timestamp appended to the log filename, you have to subclass `RotatingFileHandler` and modify the `__init__` method. Then point the `"class"` item of "`file_handler`" of the config file to your new class.

It is easy to do, but it may not be what you need.
Just let the timestamp be appended to the rotated log filename or if you need to limit the size too, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6347764/3655984)

Comment: I want every time the module is run a new log file to be generated and the timestamp should be appended to the log file

Comment: @SL' then, subclassing `RotatingFileHandler` is a way to go

Comment: @dragon2flye - I am able to get the file rotated by using the updated config , edited in my original question now , I have basically added - "interval" : 1,"when": "s" but for the same initiated python module run this spawns multiple files after each second, I want to generate only a single file for each module run and append the time stamp. So basically log files that are being generated per run with the timestamp appended , I am able to get that by 'working code' added into my original question but need to do this via a config.

Comment: @dragon2flye - I think this could be resolved if there was a way to pass the name of file in the config dynamically - 'log' + time.strftime('_%Y%m%d-%H%M')   but not sure if can be done from the config

Comment: @Infinite you are using `TimedRotatingFileHandler` in your config file but `RotatingFileHandler` in your 'working code'.  Your config file is saying that it will rotate every 1 second, so multiple files are created. Just change it back to `RotatingFileHandler` and remove the `interval` and `when` parameters.

Comment: @Infinite Even though you could use a template name in the config file, there must be a code to interpret that too. That means you have to subclass `RotatingFileHandler ` and modify the `__init__` method. But simple is the best, your workaround code is sufficient.