# logging file rotation based on size and time in config.ini

Tags: python, logging

i have a logger in a webapp, I initialize the logger from config.ini, and feed the config.ini to the app on server start.
*runApp.bat*

```
uvicorn api.main:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000 --log-config \path\logconfig.ini
```

the app is a fastAPI project.

*config.ini*

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=logfile

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s [%(thread)d] - %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
args=('C:\\path\\api.log', 'a', 1024, 1000)
```

right now the logs are rotated based on size, once it reaches 1024bytes it creates a new one what i want is to also rotate based on time so if the file has 500 bytes but for example 10 seconds pass by i want to create a new file either way

```
[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
args=('C:\\path\\api.log', 's', 10, 0)
```

this is how i call the logger in *main.py*

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
)
@app.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
.
.
.
```

adding one rotator works but i dont know how to add both?

Comment: You should be able to adapt the code given in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6347764).

Comment: for anyone wondering i ended up writing an external script the rotates them manually with scheduling.